# how to get nodeValue of child node

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an HTML table with rows similar to this one:

```
    <tr>
        <td>11/05/2013</td>
        <td>CBC W/DIFF</td>
        <td>&#xA0;</td>
        <td> <content ID="result210">Wbc: 4.5 X10E3/UL</content> </td>
        <td>Final</td>  
    </tr>
```

I want to get the nodeValue "Wbc: 4.5 X10E3/UL"

Here is my javascript code so far:

```
var table = section.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var tablebody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var rows = tablebody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
    var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    var date        = cells[0].childNodes[0].data;
    var panel       = cells[1].childNodes[0].data;
    var result      = cells[2].childNodes[0].data;
    var description = cells[3].childNodes[0];
    var content     = description.firstChild.nodeValue;  //SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'nodeValue' of undefined or null reference
    var status      = cells[4].childNodes[0].data;  
    console.log(date +" " +panel +" " +result +" " +content +" " +status);
}
```

Reported error is "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'nodeValue' of undefined or null reference"

If I comment out the description and content parts, the other fields are reported correctly so I know I'm close.
I have also tried:

```
var content =  description.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;  //SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'firstChild' of undefined or null reference 

var content = description.getElementsByTagName("content").childNodes[0].nodeValue;  //SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByTagName'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `document.getElementById("result210").innerHTML;` should work though...

Comment: You can also try : `var content = description.getElementsByTagName('content')` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first child node is a text node, due to your space in

```
<td> <content ID="result210">Wbc: 4.5 X10E3/UL</content> </td>
```

What you want is to get the first child element :

```
var content     = cells[3].children[0].innerHTML;;
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/uzayisoh/1/)

More generally, you shouldn't use nodes most of the times, as it's hard to be sure there isn't a space or new line.

Note also that it's rare to dive into the elements like this : using classes and query based selection functions, you can get a more reliable and readable code. Here, as you have an id, you should simply do

```
var content = document.getElementById("result210").innerHTML;
```

Your question isn't clear on that point : I hope you don't have elements with such id on more than one row (an id can't be given to more than one element). Supposing you have a class instead, this would be

```
var content = rows[i].getElementsByClassName("result210").innerHTML;
```

Comment: var content = description.children[0].nodeValue; //reports "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference".  Unfortunately, there is no way to know ahead of time if "result210" will be consistent for every data set.

Comment: var content = cells[3].children[0].nodeValue;  //reports "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: No, there are no duplicate ids.  I was looking at the dataset more closely and each row increments the id.  The next one is 211.  Later on though, it jumps back down to 25.  Then later it jumps down to 1.  I guess I can start with 1 and increment to the end and then sort the data by date.  That's a lot of extra work though and I'm surprised there isn't a way to do it.  I clicked your Demonstration link and see that you got the correct data.  Which of your 3 methods did you use to do that?

Comment: var content = cells[3].children[0].innerHTML;  //Reports "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference "

Comment: var content = cells[3].children[0].innerHTML; DOES work on firefox (so I'll give you credit for the answer) but not on IE 10.0.9200.16750.  Thanks microsoft.  Also unfortunately, other rows in my dataset have a text node for that cell instead of an element, so that also causes it to fail.  Man there must be a way to make this more robust.  Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I finally got it to work on both firefox and IE.  Here's my solution:   var description = cells[3].childNodes;
            var content = "content"; 
            for (j=0; j<description.length; j++) {
                if       (description[j].nodeType==1) content=description[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue;            //1=ELEMENT_TYPE
                else if ((description[j].nodeType==3) && (description.length==1)) content=description[j].data;   //3=TEXT_NODE 
            }